# Why isn't the effect of devise sign_in method immediate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

I try to sign in as other user using `sign_in(user)`

```
(byebug) user = User.find(2)
# return me the record of user with ID=2
(byebug) current_user.id
1
(byebug) sign_in(user)
# return me the record of user with ID=2
(byebug) current_user.id
1 # I expect this to be 2!!
```

Can anyone explain why?

Note: strangely, I found a new thing called `session["warden.user.user.key"].first.first` which does what I want, but it doesn't seem like the right and clean way to do.

Comment: I think `current_user` is set once for a request

Comment: why are you trying to achieve this through a debugger?

Comment: @Lenin Raj Rajasekaran That's good to know, do you know if there's documentation somewhere I can look into?

Comment: @Nithin I work through it step by step so I can inspect if things match my expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Devise source code line 50](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/715192a7709a4c02127afb067e66230061b82cf2/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb#L50) which is within the `sign_in` method says:

> # Do nothing. User already signed in and we are not forcing it.

so I think the reason is because Devise doesn't sign in a new user if we already signed in as a user (unless we force it).